# Jetpack compose remember

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I was converting my [simple paint app](https://github.com/logickoder/paint) to compose and I came across a problem that I was able to fix, this question is for help in trying to understand why it behaved the way it did earlier, I tried searching for information on it but it compose is still a bit new and no much info online.

So, here is my original code snippet.
By running this code, the lastSelected variable was always resetting back to 0 anytime I tried using it in the ColorPalette lambda, and when I checked the Tool lambda, the value was set correctly but it seems that during recomposition, the original value was retained.

```
@Composable
fun Toolbar(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, color: (Color) -> Unit, tool: (Int) -> Unit) {
    // holds the currently selected tool index
    var selected by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(0) }
    var showColorPalette by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var lastSelected = remember { 0 }

    Column(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.8f),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.End,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top,
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = bar.fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceAround,
        ) {
            Tools.mapIndexed { index, tool ->
                Tool(
                    name = tool.first, image = tool.second, selected = selected == index) {
                        selected = index
                        showColorPalette = (tool.second == R.drawable.ic_color_palette).also {
                            if (!it) {
                                lastSelected = index
                                tool(tool.second)
                            }
                        }
                   }
            }
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier
            .height(8.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth())
        ColorPalette(isVisible = showColorPalette) { color ->
            // revert the selected item back to the tool that was selected before
            selected = lastSelected
            // hide the color palette once a color is clicked
            showColorPalette = false
            // update the color used for drawing
            color(color)
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my updated code snippet,

```
@Composable
fun Toolbar(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, color: (Color) -> Unit, tool: (Int) -> Unit) {
    // holds the currently selected tool index
    var selected by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(0) }
    var showColorPalette by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var lastSelected = remember { 0 }

    fun updateColor(color: Color) {
        // revert the selected item back to the tool that was selected before
        selected = lastSelected
        // hide the color palette once a color is clicked
        showColorPalette = false
        // update the color used for drawing
        color(color)
    }

    fun updateTool(tool: Pair<String, Int>, index: Int) {
        selected = index
        showColorPalette = (tool.second == R.drawable.ic_color_palette).also {
            if (!it) {
                lastSelected = index
                tool(tool.second)
            }
        }
    }

    Column(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.8f),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.End,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top,
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = bar.fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceAround,
        ) {
            Tools.mapIndexed { index, tool ->
                Tool(
                    name = tool.first, image = tool.second,
                    selected = selected == index, onClick = { (::updateTool)(tool, index) })
            }
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier
            .height(8.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth())
        ColorPalette(isVisible = showColorPalette, onClick = ::updateColor)
    }
}
```

After a long time of frustration because I could not understand why it was happening, I had a similar type of code in my DrawingCanvas file and the variable was remembered during recomposition, the only difference between them was that the place I was accessing and updating the variable in the DrawingCanvas file was an inner function, so I applied the same in this my code snippet and it seemed to work.

The variable's value is now remembered during recomposition.

I want to understand why this happens

Comment: you need to use `mutableStateOf()` for your `lastSelected`, I suggest you start with state in Compose [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state), including [this youtube video](https://youtu.be/mymWGMy9pYI) which explains the basic principles.

Comment: I know about state but I don't want my composable to recompose because of that variable, the selected variable already does that for, I'm just trying to grasp why it seemed to work well when I passed method references to the listeners but not when I called the code directly in a lambda

Comment: Actually, changing `selected` now does not cause a recomposition, because you don't read that value anywhere. And this is the reason why `lastSelected` is able to store data for a while - it works until the next recomposition, when it is reset. If you start reading `selected`, changing two state variables at the same time, as you do in `updateColor`, will only cause one recomposition, there's no point trying to do this optimization. If you need some changeable value to survive the recomposition, mutable state is the only way to go.

Comment: I do read the selected value, when composing a Tool. I'm in no way trying to do an optimization, this was the only way I felt I could solve the problem, by storing the index of the last selected tool. My problem is when I used the first code snippet, last selected was always 0, it seemed to be reverted during recomposition but it seems to work as expected in the 2nd snippet, and that's what is confusing me.

Comment: So why don't you want to use `mutableStateOf` for `lastSelected`?

Comment: Won't that cause the composable to be recomposed when I'm accessing the last selected variable, and I don't want that

Comment: Recomposition only happens when you change value, not when you access it. And in this case you always change it together with `selected`, which means there'll be no overhead